# How do I make release apk in android studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

How do I make release version of apk in android studio 3.01?
Do I need to do in gradle?
Thanks.

Comment: nothing changes in this matter since android studio 2.0

Comment: I just instaled android studio and i am nowbie

Comment: Go to build->generate signed apk, create a keystore and follow the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Build` menu and select `Generate Signed APK`. This will bring up a wizard for you to use to generate a singed APK file.

You'll need to generate a key and keystore to sign your app. The Android documentation is quite good, I'd suggest reading [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-apk) for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio

Build -> Generate Signed APK -> Fill all the details in the dialog shown (In the KeyStore Path field, Click on Create New if you are creating for the first time) 
-> After filling the details click on Next and in the next window click on Finish.

After some time a popup will appear on the bottom right and from there you can locate your Release Version Apk